# Summer job extension

Tags: contract-extension

I got a summer job in a very reputed company for three months. But the contract said they will work with me for one month and then extend to next month. After one month my boss was leaving for holidays and my time was running out in between. She extended the period herself for one month. I kept on working on the projects and so far they are very happy with my performance. Now my boss is super busy after her holidays but she hasn't talked about extension personally but she has promised to have a meeting with me to know how my work is going like when she is fully available. Maybe she is forgetting that my time is running out by the end of this week.  Should I email her or wait for her to talk about it herself about my last month of the summer job? Because I should be working for another month.

Comment: In some jurisdictions, if you just go to work and no one stops you, you are considered employed.

Comment: @Daniel Do you have any more information about this? I am interested in this concept.

Comment: It applies in Germany, AFAIK. Used to work for a Callcenter and had to implement a function which specifically prevented agents to log in without a valid contract, because they used to make 9-month-contracts and some of the agents just kept coming, and in taking their work where effectively converted to an unlimited employment contract.

Comment: I believe this is also a more general concept in law, where, if two parties effectively act as if there was a contract, the contract is deemed to be existent. It is "conduct implying an intent" (konkludente Handlung) probably does not belong here, though.

Comment: As I said, we had rulings by labor court that said otherwise. The point is, normally you create a value at your workplace and your employer accepts the result, so he kind of agreed to you doing the "creating" If they let you train with the Patriots, and you can keep up and don´t get kicked out, they´ll probably want to hire you anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

> Should I email her or wait for her to talk about it herself about my
>   last month of the summer job?

Yes, you should send your boss an email reminder, that includes the *number of days remaining*.  I would also follow up with a **face to face conversation** since your running out of time.

There is nothing wrong with showing motivation to continue working.

Answer (score 1):

Consider connecting in person first. This is almost always the better option when available. For busy executives in-person may be too hard to schedule, in which case something like email may be better.
You'll only need 5 minutes.

- Just a reminder, my contract is up e.g. on Friday
- Is there anything you would like from me before then?
- I'd love to complete the final month, but understand if that's not possible (or some such)
- Want to make sure everything is buttoned up if I'm not returning (you may not get this far)

At some point after #1 you'll probably get the "oh, is it so close?" I will do this e.g. this afternoon, tomorrow, etc.

To which you can respond, "Great, I enjoy working with this team" or some other positive feedback.

Then you can ask, "Is there anything I can take off your plate to make this task easier?" or some such. You'll probably get a "no, it's all on me now."

Then you offer some version of "thank you" and leave. Leaving before being hinted/asked is a good "busy person" skill many lack.

If the manager is the kind of person who forgets things and/or said they will do it tomorrow AND you think it makes sense you could send a follow-up email at a strategic time. For example, if you chat on Monday and the manager says she will do it on Wednesday, then Tuesday night or very early Wednesday is a great time to send an email with:

- Thanks again for extending me
- Enjoyed 'x' over the last _ months
- Looking forward to 'y' coming up

2-3 sentences is all you need. Good luck!